# Check constraint and return the body accordingly

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show onboarding screen only for the first time user opens the application, so at the final page of Onboarding screen I put OnBoardingStatus value to be "Done" and move to the main screen. But when user opens the application for the next time this code flash the Onboarding screen for few milliseconds and then opens the mainScreen.

Here is my code

```
class App2 extends StatefulWidget {
  App2({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _App2State createState() => _App2State();
}

class _App2State extends State<App2> {
  String onBoardingStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getOnBoardingStatus();
    super.initState();


  }

  Future<void> getOnBoardingStatus() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var onboardingstatus = prefs.getString('OnBoardingStatus');
    setState(() {
      onBoardingStatus = onboardingstatus;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: onBoardingStatus != null
          ? MainScreen()
          : OnboardingScreen());
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it is not possible this way you have to pass that data from where you are navigation to this screen because async task takes time to complete.  Otherwise you can use futurebuilder and until data is not available show loading screen and when data is load then show screen accordingly.

Comment: hey @VirenVVarasadiya, can you please suggest me how to use future builder for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have no way to know if `onBoardingStatus` is null because the `SharedPreferences` instance hasn't been retrieved yet, or because the `OnBoardingStatus` really is empty. You can work around this with a `FutureBuilder`:

```
class App2 extends StatelessWidget {
  App2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<String> getOnBoardingStatus() async => 
    (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getString('OnBoardingStatus');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getOnBoardingStatus(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          //TODO: Return a widget that indicates loading
        }
        return Scaffold(
            body: snapshot.data != null
                ? MainScreen()
                : OnboardingScreen());
      },  
    );  
  }
}
```

However I don't think it's the best solution. For starters, `App2` should get the status from an outer source - this way if you ever decide to change your storage solution you wouldn't need to touch `App2`.

Comment: Facing the same problem again. onboarding screen appears for few milliseconds.

Comment: You'd have to return something inside the if statement that checks the connectionState in order to avoid that. Either return a ProgressIndicator, or just an empty Container.